# How to sort an array of strings by numerical order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

For example, i have a string array `['item 2','item 1','item 10','item 4']`. I want it to be like this `['item 1','item 2','item 4','item 10']` but by default, the `sort()` function sorts values by alphabetical order, which means it will look like this `['item 1','item 10','item 2','item 4']`

Comment: With that particular input (and its variants, a constant string following by a number), `array.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, 'EN', {numeric: true}));` will do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

Just get the number and sort it

```js
let array = ["item 1", "item 10", "item 2", "item 4"];

const result = array.sort((a, b) => a.match(/\d+/) - b.match(/\d+/));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add custom compare function in [array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
const myArr = ['item 2','item 1','item 10','item 4'];
const sortArr = myArr.sort((a, b) => {
  const num1 = Number(a.split(' ')[1]);
  const num2 = Number(b.split(' ')[1]);
  return num1 - num2;
});
console.log(sortArr);
```

or simply

```js
const myArr = ['item 2','item 1','item 10','item 4'];
const sortArr = myArr.sort((a, b) => Number(a.split(' ')[1]) - Number(b.split(' ')[1]))
console.log(sortArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a function to `sort()` method and sort it on custom way

```
let result = arr.sort((a,b) => a.split(' ')[1]-b.split(' ')[1])

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let array = ['item 1','item 10','item 2','item 4'];
var customSort = function (a, b) {
    return Number(a.replace("item ","")) - Number(b.replace("item ",""));  
}
console.log(array.sort(customSort));
//one line
console.log(array.sort((a,b) => Number(a.replace("item ","")) - Number(b.replace("item ",""))));
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a custom `sort() function` and use `slice` to get the number of the string and then apply`Number()` to transform it to a number for comparison.

Note: `sort()` will update the original array.

```js
const array = ["item 1", "item 10", "item 2", "item 4"];
array.sort((a, b) => Number(a.slice(5)) - Number(b.slice(5)));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pick any answer. This is a more generic solution, for sorting strings ending with numeric values (or not).

```js
const toNumberOrZero = str => {
  const maybeNumber = str.match(/(\d+)$/);
  return maybeNumber && +maybeNumber[0] || 0;
};
const sortNumericForStringsEndingWithNumbers = (a, b) =>
  toNumberOrZero(a) - toNumberOrZero(b);

console.log(
  ['item 2', 'item 1', 'item 10', 'item 4', 'item222', 
    'anything1023', 'notanumber', 'the meaning of life is 42']
  .sort(sortNumericForStringsEndingWithNumbers)
);
```